# No ReverseMatch : password reset activation email is not working in django?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-email

I am trying to see if `password reset` works in my `development environment`.
The `activation email` is sent out to my `console`. but when I paste it on the `browser`, I get the following error:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/password/reset/confirm/MQ/3q5-7f3106e0a0cfc67d8bee/
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'password_reset_complete' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307473/django-built-in-password-reset-views), but did not help.
Here is my urls.py;

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.conf.urls import url

from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                           url(r'^login/$',
                               auth_views.login,
                               {'template_name': 'registration/login.html'},
                               name='auth_login'),
                           url(r'^logout/$',
                               auth_views.logout,
                               {'template_name': 'registration/logout.html'},
                               name='auth_logout'),
                           url(r'^password/change/$',
                               auth_views.password_change,
                               {'post_change_redirect': reverse_lazy('auth_password_change_done')},
                               name='auth_password_change'),
                           url(r'^password/change/done/$',
                               auth_views.password_change_done,
                               name='auth_password_change_done'),
                           url(r'^password/reset/$',
                               auth_views.password_reset,
                               {'post_reset_redirect': reverse_lazy('auth_password_reset_done')},
                               name='auth_password_reset'),
                           url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$',
                               auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
                               name='auth_password_reset_confirm'),
                           url(r'^password/reset/complete/$',
                               auth_views.password_reset_complete,
                               {'post_reset_redirect': reverse_lazy('auth_password_reset_complete')},
                               name='auth_password_reset_complete'),
                           url(r'^password/reset/done/$',
                               auth_views.password_reset_done,
                               name='auth_password_reset_done'),
    )
```

How to fix this? I am using `django 1.6`
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably `{% url 'password_reset_complete' %}` somewhere in your template. Change it to

```
{% url 'auth_password_reset_complete' %}
```

Comment: I grepped my entire templates, I could not find any `{% url 'password_reset_complete' %}`

Comment: maybe quotes are different, or possibly in's in some python file (view or something). You could try removing `"auth_"` from `"auth_ password_reset_complete"` in the `urls.py`, but that is bound to create new problems.